# Reacting to each tick events from the websocket

Tags: c++, boost-asio, boost-beast, beast-websockets

I would like to design my trading system reacting to each tick events from the websocket stream i subscribed to.

So basically i have two options :

```
void WebsocketClient::on_write(beast::error_code ec,
                               std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    boost::ignore_unused(bytes_transferred);

    ws_.async_read(buffer_,
                   beast::bind_front_handler(&WebsocketClient::on_message,
                                             shared_from_this()));
}

void WebsocketClient::on_message(beast::error_code ec,
                                 std::size_t bytes_transferred) {

    // signal generation and sending http request to place new orders here
    // first before calling async_read() below

    std::cout << "Received: " << beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.cdata())
              << std::endl;

    ws_.async_read(buffer_,
                   beast::bind_front_handler(&WebsocketClient::on_message,
                                             shared_from_this()));
}
```

Or i could

```
void WebsocketClient::on_message(beast::error_code ec,
                            std::size_t bytes_transferred) {
    ws_.async_read(buffer_,
                   beast::bind_front_handler(&WebsocketClient::on_message,
                                             shared_from_this()));

    // signal generation and sending http request to place new orders here after
    // calling async_read()

    std::cout << "Received: " << beast::buffers_to_string(buffer_.cdata())
              << std::endl;
}
```

please give me your suggestions and other ideas i could look at! advance thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There would be no tangible difference, unless

```
// signal generation and sending http request to place new orders here
// first before calling async_read() below
```

either

- takes significant amount of time (design smell on IO threads)
- exits the function by return/exception

That's because `async_read` by definition [always returns immediately](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/ref/boost__beast__websocket__stream/async_read.html#:%7E:text=This%20call%20always%20returns%20immediately)

Comment: I mean in the first case if signal generation and placing of new orders is done before async_read then that IO thread is not blocked by that processing stage right ? And in the second case where callling async_read first before processing means completion handler on_message() will call after recieving new event while that processing(signal generation and placing of new orders) stage is still continued on the same IO thread, is that a problem ? @sehe

Comment: True. Like I said, it makes a difference if that takes a significant amount of time. What "significant" means depends on your application. If you don't want it on your IO thread, don't do that.

Comment: (sry for the ping again) @sehe just to clarify again, so i have two options here.

1) call async_read() after u have send the orders and all that signal generation stuffs
2) or do signal generations stuffs on other thread and keep IO thread running without any blockage

I think the best option here is the first one right ? cuz why would i need to continue running websocket stream if i dont need that data when my bot already got the data it needed for further processing, and when that is done i start again. so the first one is ideal right ?

Comment: It depends *only* on your use case. Also there might be a flaw in your reasoning. Unless you reconnect the websocket each read, you might be forgetting that it is stream-oriented. So even if you "don't need that data" you will inevitably read it - because you'll read all the messages sequentially.

Comment: It really does sound like separating IO and processing makes more sense for your use-case. But we can't tell, because we have no idea about the volume of traffic coming in, the cost of "work" being done in your comment-lines and the volume/frequency of transactions generated. Even given all that, we don't know what rate limits apply for your server access. All in all, *you* and only *you* can be responsible for chosing the right balance here.